# Code to open Instagram in Android application using PHP

Tags: php, android

I need to open Instagram app from Android app and send an image with a caption. Can any one  send the code or process to open Instagram in Android application through PHP. As the code is working fine in iPhone and iPad with using iPhone hooks.

However in Android these hooks are not working. I am sharing the code in PHP which we have integrated. Is there any other way to integrate in PHP?

Please check the given below link which is working fine for iPhone and iPad.

```
instagram://camera?caption=%23ASIFESTEJOYO_<?php echo $contestCode;?>%20%23celebremosjuntos.
```

Comment: chitra,this is not the correct way to ask question do research first about your requirments,mention your research about the problem,then ask what problem you are facing,and do read FAQ to use stackoverflow in efficient way.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](https://github.com/kpbird/android-instagram-integration).It is tutorial for integrating instagram with your android app

Comment: Thanks for sharing the information but i need the code which i can integrate in my web we are using php. We are creating any application the code run from are web side.